# Is this a dimensionality reduction problem?

Tags: statistical-significance, categorical-data, dimensionality-reduction

I have an interesting (hopefully) data science problem and I want to post it here for discussion.

Let's say we have a data set having **ONE** numerical column and **FIVE** categorical columns. For categorical columns, they have different number of unique levels. Below provides a sample.

```
A: A1, A2, ..., A5
B: B1, B2, ..., B100
C: C1, C2, C3
D: D1, D2
E: E1, E2, ..., E10

F: numerical column
```

I want to summarize `F` (e.g., students' score) with different combinations of the categorical columns. However, if certain categorical columns have *too* many levels (e.g., `B` has `100` levels in the sample above), then the number of combinations will be huge (e.g., `5 * 100 * 3 * 2 * 10 = 30000`). In addition, for certain combinations, the cohort (sample) size is super small, and summarizing `F` with such combination provides little data insight since there is almost no statistical significance.

My question is how can we *automatically* select categorical columns to summarize `F`? Can we treat it as a *dimensionality reduction* problem? Any input is appreciated.

---

**Appendix**

Here I want to elaborate more on summarizing `F`. For now, I want to calculate summary statistics of `F`, such as mean and median. Below I provide a sample SQL code.

```sql
SELECT A, B, C, D, E, AVG(F)
FROM data.frame
GROUP BY A, B, C, D, E
```

Comment: Are the categories within each column ordered, like, for example, grades of "A", "B", "C"...?

Comment: No, there is no order.

Comment: Hi Sophia! Can you elaborate a bit on what you mean by "I want to summarize `F` with different combinations of the categorical columns"? Do you mean predicting F (from the categories and their combinations), or do you mean something else?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Let me elaborate more on the question.

Comment: @J-J-J Just added the appendix section. Please let me know if more clarification is needed.